# Which is the more efficient way to accumulate a vector?

Tags: r, recursion, vector, accumulate

Which of the following is more efficient in terms of time to completion?

```
one.way = function(n) { if (n) c(n, one.way(n-1)) }
two.way = function(n) { if (n) c(two.way(n-1), n) }
```

The emphasis here is on which order to combine a singleton vector with another vector whose length is likely greater than one.

How would your answer change if you need to include the time to reverse the vector after constructing it with one of the above functions? It may or may not be known at the time of combination in which order the combined objects are going to be needed.

Comment: They're both super slow because [growing things without preallocating memory is slow](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf#chapter.2). In this case, `seq` or `:` will be much, much faster.

Comment: As stated, "the emphasis here is on which order to combine a singleton vector with another vector whose length is likely greater than one." I've given a trivial example, but many other cases are possible.

Comment: I know. The point is _don't_. Vectorize your operations instead, or at least preallocate a vector of the appropriate length, or R is going to get agonizingly slow.

Comment: Are you suggesting not to combine singleton vectors with vectors of length 1 or greater? Please clarify. Here is a simpler situation: would you do `c(1, vec)` or `c(vec, 1)`, where `vec` is a vector of arbitrary length?

Comment: I'm saying not to do it recursively/iteratively; there are better approaches. If you're doing it once, you choose `c(1, vec)` or `c(vec, 1)` depending on what you want first in the output.

Comment: Are there *compelling* reasons to take the recursive / iterative approach? Doing something iteratively in R through loops is rarely the first answer to a problem, because of the problem alistaire highilghted above. If you feel you must use it, please elaborate on your situation & explain why other approaches won't work. Right now this sounds like it may be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: The question is not about recursion. Recursion is simply one way to accumulate a vector. I used recursion in order to produce two, compact, easily comparable approaches, the difference between which relates precisely to the question.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, they're about equal

Use `microbenchmark` to test the performance of two fast functions

```
one.way = function(n) { c(n, 1) }
two.way = function(n) { c(1, n) }

n <- 2:100

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(one.way(n), two.way(n), times=1e5)

#       expr   min    lq     mean median    uq      max neval
# one.way(n) 1.399 1.866 2.009775  1.867 1.867 2817.733 1e+05
# two.way(n) 1.399 1.866 2.086267  1.867 1.867 3394.808 1e+05
```

Notice the lower-quartile, median, and upper-quartile are all the same. The means are slightly different but it's not significant. See below

```
myfun <- function(n) {
              temp <- microbenchmark(one.way(n), two.way(n), times=1e5)
              df <- data.frame(one.way = mean(temp$time[temp$expr=="one.way(n)"]),
                           two.way = mean(temp$time[temp$expr=="two.way(n)"]))
              return(df)
     }

library(purrr)
test <- map_df(1:100, ~myfun(n))

t.test(test$one.way, test$two.way)

# data:  test$one.way and test$two.way
# t = -1.6506, df = 182.72, p-value = 0.1005
# alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
```

Comment: While the other thread's discussion on the aversion of recursion is appreciated, I thank you for answering the actual question.